# Editing list elements using comprehension deletes part of list

Tags: python, list, compression

I have a number of nested lists from a web scraped table that I want to 'clean' by removing unhelpful HTML characters. They look like this:

```
example_list = ['12.7x55 mm PS12B',
  '<td style="border-bottom:solid 2px">102\n</td>',
  '<td style="border-bottom:solid 2px">46\n</td>',
  '<td style="border-bottom:solid 2px">57\n</td>',
  '<td style="border-bottom:solid 2px; background-color:#00990080;">6\n</td>',
  '<td style="border-bottom:solid 2px; background-color:#00640080;">5\n</td>',
  '<td style="border-bottom:solid 2px; background-color:#FB9C0E80;">4\n</td>']
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
my_list =  ['12.7x55 mm PS12B', '102', '46', '57', '6', '5', '4']
```

I tried simple comprehensions:

```
my_list[1:] = [i.replace('\n</td>', '') for i in list] # works perfectly
my_list[1:] = [i.replace('<td>', '') for i in list] # works perfectly
# for example the second item in the list is now `102`
# not `<td style="border-bottom:solid 2px">102\n</td>`
```

but when I try to edit the last six elements using a more specific comprehension:

```
my_list[1:] = [i.replace(i, i[-1]) for i in list if "back" in i]
```

It deletes all other list elements that I have just extracted, and I end up with:

```
my_list =  ['12.7x55 mm PS12B', '6', '5', '4']
```

I am sure being HTML there is a less obscure method to do this (which I would appreciate knowing) but my main concern is that I don't understand what's going on with a simple python comprehension.

Comment: that's scraped data. why don't you use your scraping library?

Comment: and your last line is wrong `my_list[4:] = [i.replace(i, i[-1]) for i in list if "back" in i]` should be what you want. but use beautifulsoup instead

Comment: Apart from the fact that you should use a library like [bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), 
you are overwriting the values because you use "my_list[1:]=". I'm not quite sure if you fully understand slicing in python.

Comment: I'm actually using beautiful soup I just couldn't extract the numbers cleanly so I thought instead I try a longer winded route and practice using comprehensions.

Comment: I think I have attempted the worst lazy shortcut of my life, as it would have been easier to troubleshoot problem A rather than create and troubleshoot problem B.

Comment: `[BeautifulSoup(i).get_text().strip() for i in example_list]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rest of the elements are filtered out by the `if` condition in the comprehension. If you wish to keep them, you need to add the `else` clause:

```py
my_list[1:] = [
    i.replace(i, i[-1])
    for i in list
    if "back" in i
    else i  # or however you wish to process the rest of the elements
]
```